# Simplificar função em JS

Tags: javascript, html

Queria saber como simplificar essa função tendo dois modals diferentes, é possivel ?

```
// Modal Carrinho
const abrirModal = document.querySelector('[data-modal="abrir"]');
const fecharModal = document.querySelector('[data-modal="fechar"]');
const container = document.querySelector('[data-modal="container"]');
abrirModal.addEventListener('click', mudarModal);
fecharModal.addEventListener('click', mudarModal);
container.addEventListener('click', fechaModal);

function mudarModal(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  container.classList.toggle('ativo');
}

function fechaModal(e){
  if(e.target === this){
    mudarModal(e);
  }
}

//Modal Compra
const abrirModal2 = document.querySelector('[data-modal="abrirCompra"]');
const fecharModal2 = document.querySelector('[data-modal="fecharCompra"]');
const container2 = document.querySelector('[data-modal="containerCompra"]');
abrirModal2.addEventListener('click', mudarModal2);
fecharModal2.addEventListener('click', mudarModal2);
container2.addEventListener('click', fechaModal2);

function mudarModal2(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  container2.classList.toggle('ativo');
}

function fechaModal2(e){
  if(e.target === this){
    mudarModal(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível, a parte que varia é o seletor da modal ( `[data-modal="abrir"]`), então pode criar uma *function* que receba esse valor (pode ser o final do seletor, já que o resto é igual, por exemplo "compras"), assim:

```
function criarModal(nome) {
   var abrirModal = document.querySelector('[data-modal="abrir' + nome + '"]');
   var fecharModal = document.querySelector('[data-modal="fechar' + nome + '"]');
   var container = document.querySelector('[data-modal="container' + nome + '"]');

   abrirModal.addEventListener('click', function(){
     mudarModal(this, container);
   });

   fecharModal.addEventListener('click', function(){
     mudarModal(this, container);
   });

   container.addEventListener('click', fechaModal);
}

function mudarModal(e, container){
  e.preventDefault();
  container.classList.toggle('ativo');
}

function fechaModal(e){
  if(e.target === this){
    mudarModal(e);
  }
}


// E para usar:
criarModal("");
criarModal("Compra");
```

Sempre que for refatorar um código para que ele possa ser reutilizado, destaque as pertes comuns e coloque num método/funcão/etc, e passe por parametros somente a parte que muda ou é variável, essa é a ideia, um bom ponto de partida para começar a reaproveitar código.

Tem boas perguntas com exemplos sobre isso aqui no site, sugiro pesquisar por [reutilizar codigo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=reutilizar%20codigo) e vai encontra muitas coisa.

Comment: Opa, obrigado por responder. Eu tentei usar o codigo que vc refatorou e tive o seguinte problema quando tentei abrir um modal "modal.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: container is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.mudarModal", isso acontece na hora de mudar a classe

Comment: verdade, precisa passar o container por parametro, eu editei a resposta